# z3.z3types.Z3Exception: model is not available

Tags: z3, z3py

I'm using the latest `z3py` build release (x64) in Win10 x64, python 2.7 x64.

When I try to call `model` on this constraint:

```
(i2 % 59) == (i2 * i10) , (i10 % 43) == ((i2 + i12) % 3) , 4 != (i14 % 28) , 
5 != (i14 % 28) , 6 != (i14 % 28) , 7 != (i14 % 28) , 8 != (i14 % 28) , (i2 
- i12) >= (i12 + i10) , ((i2 - i1) - (i2 * i1)) >= (i1 - 50) , (i12 - i2) < 
(i2 * i12)
```

It throws the following exception:

```
z3.z3types.Z3Exception: model is not available.
```

All the variables (e.g. `i2, i10, etc` are Integer)

I noted that `check` produce empty for this constraint.

Does that mean that this constraint is unsat?

Comment: *could you post the whole source code?*

Comment: `check` needs to be called first, and only if it returns SAT there will be a model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*`check` needs to be called first, and only if it returns SAT there will be a model.*

From @Christoph's comment.

Thanks.